# Как вывести данные с другого сайта к себе?

Tags: php

Допустим есть такой сайт https://mtasa.com/count/, в котором находится 2 значения через запятую и мне эти значения нужно вывести на свой сайт раздельно, как это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Парсинг наше все... `$html = file_get_html('https://mtasa.com/count/');
$a_links = $html->find('элемент, Типо div');`

Comment: Мне нужно что бы 1 значение до запятой у меня на сайте допустим выводилось в <h1> , а второе значение после запятой выводилось в <h2>

Comment: Сначала парсим, затем разделяем через запятую explode(",", переменная куда упало твоё число); ну а как вывести на сайт, то надеюсь разберётесь

Comment: Трудно, я знаю html, а с php тьма , помогите, покажите пожалуйста полный пример

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение довольно простое.

```
    $document = 'https://mtasa.com/count/'; # Ссылка на документ
    $fileContent = file_get_contents($document); # Получаем содержимое документа
    
    /**
     * Теперь же в переменной $file у нас содержится содержимое страница @url $document
     *
     * Вывести содержимое можно любым удобным для вас способом, к примеру оператором echo
     */
    echo $fileContent;
```

Как вы написали выше, вы хотите разделить данные "до" запятой и "после". Сделать это можно функцией explode(), которая переобразует нашу строку документа в массив.

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents($document); # Получаем содержимое документа
$wordArray = explode(',', $fileContent);

echo '<h1>' . 'Первые цифры - это: ' . $wordArray[0] . '</h1>';
echo '<h2>' . 'Вторые цифры - это: ' . $wordArray[1] . '</h2>';
```

Если вам помог мой ответ, сделайте соответствующее действие нажав на галочку у ответа.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

разделите свой большой вопрос на два. Первый - как получить данные с другого сайта.

тут все довольно тривиально. надо отправить get-запрос по указанному адресу, взять контент, разобрать его и получить данные. В вашем случае для этого будет достаточно примерно следующего кода

```
$content = file_get_contents("https://mtasa.com/count/");
[$h1, $h2] = explode(",", $content);
```

в итоге вы получите оба искомых значения.
Теперь встает вопрос, когда надо их получать. Очевидно, если вы при обработке каждого запроса будете дублировать запрос к этому сайту, то это плохой вариант. Поэтому следует изучить, как часто меняются данные на указанном сайте, оформить выше обозначенный код в виде отдельного скрипта, и назначить его выполнение по расписанию (cron) согласно графику обновления данных.
Данные эти вы сохраните где-то у себя. В файле, или в базе, или еще как-то.
Банально модифицируете:

```
<?php
   $content = file_get_contents(....);
   file_put_contents("./data/x.txt", $content);
```

а уже в своем коде на странице будете читать свой файл/базу/т.п. и выводить данные

```
<?php 
      ....
      $content = file_get_contents("./data/x.txt");
      [$h1, $h2] = explode($content)  ;


      echo "<h1>$h1</h1>";
```

Comment: И вам спасибо большое!